# SSIS: How to disable task?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I would like to keep a task in an SSIS package but enable/disable it when i please.  Is there a way to do this?

Is this big business?

Answer (score 12):

On the SSIS package's `Control Flow` tab, you can right-click on a control flow task and select **Disable** option to disable the task. Refer screenshot #**1**. If the task is already disabled, the option will read as **Enable**. Refer screenshot #**2**.

However, the tasks within `Data Flow Task` cannot be disabled. Refer screenshot #**3**.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

Comment: Microsoft said in 2010, they wouldn't be adding disable to the `Data Flow Task` which is a shame: [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/410210/ssis-add-enable-disable-within-data-flow-tab)

Comment: is there any way to see that it's disabled besides right clicking and noticing that it says "enable" instead of "disable"? Seems like this could be a very frustrating thing to troubleshoot if it's disabled and you didn't know it.

Comment: nevermind... Now I see that it turns gray when it's disabled. I was running the package so it didn't change to gray right away.

Comment: It sucks that Microsoft doesn't prioritize the ability to disable Data Flow sub-components.   It's valuable yet it would probably take a jr. programmer only 4 hours.

Comment: 2019 and still the same: Disabling Data Flow sub-components is not available.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot disable tasks in a data flow, but you can right click and disable tasks in a control flow. To get around the first problem, I copy the dataflow task in the control flow and paste it. Disable the  new dataflow task and then delete what I don't want to execute out of the old dataflow task steps. Then at least I still have the orginal steps to copy into the data flow I'm using as I want to add them.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a Conditional Split:

Condition 1: 1 == 1 it will run the following Tasks.
Condition 2: 1 == 2 it will not run the following Tasks.

Just Change conditions as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to right-click on the task and select Disable.

Comment: hmm, i do not see that option is there any other way you know of ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also select multiple tasks with the mouse by dragging a box around them (click on upper left corner, drag to lower right,) right-click, and get the popup menu with the 'disable' option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the package isn't currently executing.  But yea, should be a right click away.